# Testing if a dictionary key ends in a letter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
tools = {"Wooden_Sword1" : 10, "Bronze_Helmet1 : 20}
```

I have code written to add items, i'm adding an item like so:

```
tools[key_to_find] = int(b)
```

the `key_to_find` is the tool and the `b` is the durability and i need to find a way so if i'm adding and `Wooden_Sword1` already exists it adds a `Wooden_Sword2` instead. This has to work with other items as well

Comment: To make this easier to extend (and create in the first place), why not have a single `Wooden_Sword` key, then have a list of tuples with `(id, durability)` as the values.  You could very quickly have a large number of very similar keys that are hard to keep track of.

Comment: @user3483203: Or just skip the `id`; the position of the `durability` in the `list` is its ID. New unique IDs are generated with a simple `append` to the `list`.

Comment: Yep that too, pretty much anything to avoid keys `Wooden_Sword1-Wooden_Sword9999` :P

Comment: any reason I haven't seen anyone mention that dictionary.keys() returns a list of the keys in a dictionary?

Comment: @tgikal: It's almost never necessary to use `keys()`. The dictionary is iterable, yielding its keys directly (and the `in` operator checks for keys in the dictionary as well). You're also not quite right that `keys` returns a list (that used to be true in Python 2, but is not any more). These days it returns a dictionary view object, which has some of the `set` API but doesn't need to copy any data (it just looks it up in the dictionary object).

Comment: I was not even aware of the in operator working like that, good to know.

Answer (score 2):

As [user3483203](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3483203/user3483203) and [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) commented, it's probably a bad idea to use numbers in your key string as part of the data. Manipulating those numbers will be awkward, and there are better alternatives. For instance, rather than storing a single value for each numbered key, use simple keys and store a list. The index into the list will take the place of the number in the key.

Here's how you could implement it:

```
tools = {"Wooden_Sword" : [10], "Bronze_Helmet" : [20]}
```

Add a new wooden sword with durability 10:

```
tools.setdefault("Wooden_Sword", []).append(10)
```

Find how many bronze helmets we have:

```
helmets = tools.get("Bronze_Helmet", [])
print("we have {} helmets".format(len(helmets)))
```

Find the first bronze helmet with a non-zero durability, and reduce it by 1:

```
helmets = tools.get("Bronze_Helmet", [])
for i, durability in helmets:
    if durability > 0:
         helmets[i] -= 1
         break
else: # this runs if the break statement was never reached and the loop ran to completion
    take_extra_damage() # or whatever
```

You could simplify some of this code by using a `collections.defaultdict` instead of a regular dictionary, but if you learn how to use `get` and `setdefault` it's not too hard to get by with the regular `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the question, your keys have 2 parts: "Name" and "ID". The ID is just an integer that starts at 1, so you can initialize a counter for every name:

```
numOfWoodenSwords = 0
```

And to add to the array:

```
numOfWoodenSwords += 1
tools["wodden_sword" + str(numOfWoodenSwords)] = int(b)
```

If you need to have an unknown amount of tools, I recommend looking at the re module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html.

Or you could iterate over `tools.keys` to see if the entry exists.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure a key name is not taken yet, and add a number if it is, create the new name and test. Then increment the number if it is already in your list. Just repeat until none is found.

In code:

```
def next_name(basename, lookup):
    if basename not in lookup:
        return basename
    number = 1
    while basename+str(number) in lookup:
        number += 1
    return basename+str(number)
```

While this code does what you ask, you may want to look at other methods. A possible drawback is that there is no *association* between, say, `WoodenShoe1` and `WoodenShoe55` – if 'all wooden shoes' need their price increased, you'd have to iterate over all *possible* names between `1` and `55`, just in case these existed at some time.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that determines if a character is a letter:

```
def is_letter(char):
    return 65 <= ord(char) <= 90 or 97 <= ord(char) <= 122
```

Then when you are looking at a key in your dictionary, simply:

```
if is_letter(key[-1]):
    ...
```